# Wanting wxWidgets Memory Leak Exception

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets application (wxApp).  I am using Visual Studio 2010.

_CrtSetDbgFlag is set in the application's OnInit method.

I would like for the application to throw an exception if a memory leak is detected on exit.  I expect this could be done by directly modifying wxWidgets where it dumps the memory leaks, but I would much rather know if there's a standard way to do this instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets doesn't dump memory leaks itself, the dumps you're seeing are done by MSVC CRT. So whatever you need to do should be done at its level. `_CrtSetReportHook()` might be useful.

Comment: I have been able to get an exception thrown from a _CrtSetReportHook callback.  However, it hasn't dumped the memory leaks yet.  Calling _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks manually within my callback causes a stack overflow.

Comment: @IanMallett: Your hook is called before the leaks are dumped so (as an example) you can filter the dump. If you then call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` your're probably ending up calling the same function over and over until you get a stack overflow. You could try manually calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` from e.g. your `OnExit()` handler, set a flag in your hook function, and then after `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` returns throw your exception.

Comment: Within the wxApp's OnExit method, wx hasn't cleaned itself up entirely--even by the end of the function, so _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); returns tons of false positives.